# How to traverse an FSharp.Data HtmlDocument to extract content as a string?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'd like to write a function that gets me from this html:

```html
<div>
  <h1>Some header.</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>What is going on? <a href="http://example.com">This is a link</a>.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

to this string:

> Some header. Hello world! What is going on? This is a link.

In other words: I'd like to make this test pass:

```ml
let testInput: string = """
<div>
  <h1>Some header.</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>What is going on? <a href="http://example.com">This is a link</a>.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
"""

let getContentsFromHtmlDocument (doc: HtmlDocument) =
  let getInner (node: HtmlNode): string =
    // How can I traverse this tree?
    ""
  let result =
    doc.Descendants ["h1"; "p"; "a"]
    |> Seq.map getInner
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> List.fold (+) ""
  result

[<Test>]
let Test1 () =
    let htmlDoc: HtmlDocument = HtmlDocument.Parse(testInput)
    let res = getContentsFromHtmlDocument htmlDoc
    Assert.AreEqual("Some header. Hello world! What is going on? This is a link.", res)
```

But I'm having trouble figuring how to traverse the tree. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extension method in `HtmlNodeExtensions`, which provides methods you'd normally use to walk the tree. For your particular use case there is `HtmlNodeExtensions.DirectInnerText(n)`.

Although, to pass your test, you'd need space separated inner text, which is much more efficiently done by `String.Join`.

```
let getContentsFromHtmlDocument (doc: HtmlDocument) =
    let getInner (node: HtmlNode): string =
        node.DirectInnerText()

    let result =
        doc.Descendants ["h1"; "p"; "a"]
        |> Seq.map getInner
        |> fun all -> String.Join(" ", all)

    result
```

There's still the matter of:

```
<p>What is going on? <a href="http://example.com">This is a link</a>.</p>
```

This would join to:

`What is going on? . This is a link` as opposed to  `What is going on? This is a link.` which can't be handled with your current structure.